# Update DataGridView DataSource Immediately When TextBox Value Changed

Tags: datagridview

I have a simple DataGridView that is bound to a list of business objects (with just one editable field per object). I need any changes that the user makes to the value (which is in a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) to update the bound object.  That is, cause an update for every keypress in the same way that is available when binding a normal textbox and using the 'OnPropertyChanged' option.

The reason for this is that I simply need to enable the 'OK' button on the form when the bound object's 'IsDirty' property is true.

There seems to be many discussions on various websites about doing this for checkbox columns and using the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event and calling CommitEdit.  I have tried this but this had the unfortunate side effect of clearing the cell of all text on the first keypress!

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you actually need to update the datasource? Couldn't you instead simply use the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event and enable the button? The datasource should update when the focus is lost when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to enable the button as soon as the user starts typing in any cell? Does the `DataSource` actually need to be updated before the button is clicked?

If not then `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` should work fine for that - just don't call the `CommitEdit` method, instead set your button to enabled there.

When the cell loses focus the changes will be applied to the `DataSource` - so when the button is clicked you will be able to work on the correct data.

---

I think I may have found a solution - not 100% sure since I don't have the MVC controller you have to wire up the IsDirty change and see it all work - I did put a break point in a property setter on my DataSource object and it gets fired with the following code and not without it, so I think this works.

It simply used the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged and the CurrentCellChange enum for the DataErrorContext parameter.

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange);
}
```

Comment: That is the effect I want yes, but I have a Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture so the work has to be done in the objects. The button is enabled when the object is dirty, not directly by code on the form.

Comment: I've found that when trying to get an MV* architecture (I use MVP for winforms) databinding gets in the way.

Comment: @Darren - also, a thought on the architecture, unless you are going for a really strict passive view, can't you send a message from the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event to your controller and then make the necessary changed to the view - databinding doesn't necessarily need to come into it.

Comment: I may have to go with something like that (perhaps a 'MarkEditingStarted' method and 'HasEditingStarted' flag, but the logic of whether the button is enabled is whether an object in the list is dirty. That logic is simple and correct and I would like to keep it like that.

Comment: That is similar to the code I mentioned in my original question (with different argument passed) that results in the text being cleared somehow in the CommitEdit process.  Your code with the different argument has the same effect. I'm trying to step through DataGridView source code to see if I can see how it occurs exactly but as you can imagine, it's not too easy to see what's going on.

Comment: Now I have realised that the text isn't cleared on all types of edit, it just so happens that I was testing by deleting a character with the Delete key and this causes the text to be cleared. If I type a character, it appears as expected but annoyingly, the whole text is selected so the next keypress will clear the text.

Comment: It works beautifully if a PropertyChanged event is not raised in the property setter. Not much use as a solution though.

Comment: @Darren - ah, so I'm guessing that at this point the propertychanged being pushed to the grid is confusing things. If I was you I'd go with the simple MarkEditingStarted and HasEditingStarted solution - not 100% elegant but should work and be robust atleast (and start trying to convince people to look at WPF for the next project)

Comment: @David Hall - I agree, I think I will go with that. Thanks for your efforts.